# How to copy/backup all ubuntu files in a way I can read them without restoring?

Tags: backup

I am looking for a good way to backup my linux partition in a way that I can access the backuped files from a Windows pc. I want the entire drive backed up because I want to make sure I have all data and config files saved if I need them again because Im going to reinstall my computer. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with a full backup of Ubuntu. Windows only reads Windows formatted partitions like NTFS or FAT32, but those formats do not support ownership & permissions which are required for Linux.

You can copy data files like photos, music or text to NTFS as ownership or permissions are not critical and can be easily reset when copied back into a new Linux install.

But if a full backup you need all of /home, possibly some of /etc if you changed any system or hardware configurations and export a list of installed applications to make it easy to reinstall. Some other applications may have data in other locations such as sql or other server type data.

You can use many tools to copy data, in uncompressed format or others in compressed formats that need others tools to read. But almost all only work from Linux, but you can use a liveCD or flash drive to read that data.

discussion of alternatives/strategy backups

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

If you install your own system you are the system admin
Sysadmins: Everything they told you about backup WAS A LIE

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/07/12/storagebod_monomyth/

Comment: There are ext2/3/4 drivers for Windows, [like this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html).

Comment: I copied all my data to an ntfs folder. File permissions aren't that important because I am mainly concerned about my personal documents and some config files. In case of the config files, I'll just check the original file right before replacing them with my backup and use chmod to correct it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find anything online about this, but I imagine you can make the files viewable from a simple copy+paste?  I don't think there is any way to view the files in an actual backup unless you plan to copy and paste your files around.

If all goes wrong you could just make a list of what you need and re-download it all.

I'm pretty sure I'm wrong but at least I opened this topic to a bit of discussion

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Windows-Files-in-Ubuntu I know it's the opposite to want you want but at least its a stepping stone.